# how to use proc in named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the rails 3 for my app ,in that i need to use the proc for named scope but it is not working form me

```
scope :donate_list,Proc.new {|nonprofit,event| where("zip IN (?) AND category_id IN (?)",nonprofit,event)}
```

where its getting wrong

Comment: it does work for me, what do the log says?

Answer (score 3):

Try with a lambda:

```
scope :donate_list, lambda {|nonprofit,event| where("zip IN (?) AND category_id IN (?)",nonprofit,event)}
```